# Wordpress: Using post__not_in to exclude custom taxonomy category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to exclude the items within a custom taxonomy category (slug: private-case-study, ID: 5) from a loop. I'm using the following code, does anyone have suggestions or ideas why it's not working? Thanks in advance!

```
    // Get the current page ID
        $this_post = $post->ID;
        $private_case_study = get_term_by('slug', 'private-case-study', 'mgt_portfolio_filter');


        // Show items from specific category
        if($category_name == '') {
            $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'mgt_portfolio',
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
                'orderby'    => $orderby,
                'order' => $order,
                'post__not_in' => array($this_post, $private_case_study)
            ));
        } else {
            $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'mgt_portfolio',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'mgt_portfolio_filter',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $category_name,
                    ),
                ),
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
                'orderby'    => $orderby,
                'post__not_in' => array($this_post, $private_case_study),
                'order' => $order
            ));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

//Get the current page ID
        $this_post = $post->ID;
        $private_case_study = get_term_by('slug', 'private-case-study', 'mgt_portfolio_filter');

```
    // Show items from specific category
    if($category_name == '') {
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'mgt_portfolio',
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'orderby'    => $orderby,
            'order' => $order,
            'post__not_in' => array($this_post)
        ));
    } else {
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'mgt_portfolio',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'mgt_portfolio_filter',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $category_name,
                ),
            ),
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'orderby'    => $orderby,
            'post__not_in' => array($this_post),
            'order' => $order
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`post__not_in` takes an array of IDs and excludes them. You want to being using `category__not_in` which takes an array of category IDs and excludes them.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I'm trying to exclude the posts within a custom taxonomy category. Would `category__not_in` do the same thing?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but that should be what ```category__not_in``` does. It will take an array of category IDs, and not display posts in those categories. ```post__not_in``` takes an array of post IDs and doesn't display those individual posts. So if 'private-case-study' has an ID of 1, and you include ```'category__not_in' => array(1);```, it will exclude all posts in that category.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks! I've tried adding that in but it's still showing the items within that category. Here's what I added-
`'post__not_in' => array($this_post),
'category__not_in' => array(5)`

Anything I'm missing? This isn't the default Wordpress blog post category, it's a custom one that comes with the theme. Would I have to specify the category type or something? Appreciate your help!

Comment: I might have been pointing you in the wrong direction. Take a look at the [answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12217/how-do-i-exclude-a-custom-taxonomy-from-the-post-loop). Does that help at all?

Comment: That definitely helped, thank you so much! I added the `'tax_query' => array'` to the `if` statement and used the `'operator'  => 'NOT IN'` property, which got it to work. Much appreciated!